# How to get grouped data from a microservice?

Tags: microservices

Let's say we have a system to store appointments. Each appointment has multiple resources (e.g. trainers, rooms, etc.). We have decided to move all appointment data into an Appointment Service and all resources into a Resources Service.

Now we need a UI that shows filters for the appointments, to filter by trainer. Usually, you only want to display checkboxes for trainers that actually have appointments and not all trainers.

That means we can't really use the Resource Service to get all trainers, instead, we would have to ask the Appointment Service to get a grouped view of all trainers that have at least one appointment. Then we would have to call the Resource Service to get more info about each trainer.

So how do you get grouped data from a microservice?

Edit: Each system has it's own database. We also use RabbitMQ to sync data between services.

Comment: This is a very open question - there are many possible solutions, such as denormalized data structures, partitioning strategies, etc. The right solution will depend on what scale you're considering and where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question with many possible solutions. @Welbog comment makes a good point about it depending on the scale of the application. Denormalized databases are obviously a possibility.

Getting grouped data is one of the challenges of implementing microservices, and this challenge becomes greater the more granular our services get. What does your database setup look like? I'm assuming your two services are using different databases otherwise your question would have a simple solution.

Without knowing the ins and outs of your system, I would assume that **denormalizing your db's** would be the path of least resistance.

You could possible explore the idea that **maybe these two services should in fact be a single service**. Nanoservices are not what we are after, and sometimes it just makes more logical sense for two services to actually be together. Things that must change together, should be contained together. I'm not saying this is applicable in your case, I'm just saying it's worth considering.

I'm certain others will have other ideas, but based on what little I know about the entirety of your system, it's hard to say; however I think this is an interesting question that I will follow to see what other peoples proposed solutions are.